# Apagar Diretório Raiz em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou criando um sistema que apaga e cria novamente as pastas de um diretório até a criação das pastas esta tudo ok, porém tentei utlizar o camando abaixo para apagaro um diretório Raiz da minha aplicação porem ele só aceita excluir pastas vazias. Alguem sabe me indicar algo que eu possa fazer para apagar o diretório completo.

### segue exexmplo abaixo

```
import os

#variaveis
user00= os.listdir(r'D:\Publico\PA00_SEDE')
user99 = os.listdir(r'D:\Publico\PA99_ADMINISTRATIVO')
users = os.listdir(r'D:\Publico\PA01_FARMÁCIA')
users7 = os.listdir(r'D:\Publico\PA02_7_SETEMBRO')
users15 = os.listdir(r'D:\Publico\PA03_15_NOVEMBRO')
users4 = os.listdir(r'D:\Publico\PA04_JUNDIAÍ')


#Neste ponto é onde tenho o problema
#Este é o diretório raiz de outras varias subpastas, porem nao posso apagar com
#o metodo abaixo pois ele só apaga diretórios vazios
***os.rmdir(r'D:\Publico')*** 


#laços para criar as pastas
for x in user00:
    os.makedirs(r'D:\Publico\PA00_SEDE\\'+x)

for x in user99:
    os.makedirs(r'D:\Publico\PA99_ADMINISTRATIVO\\'+x)


for x in users:
    os.makedirs(r'D:\Publico\PA01_FARMÁCIA\\'+x)

for x in users7:
    os.makedirs(r'D:\Publico\PA02_7_SETEMBRO\\'+x)

for x in users15:
    os.makedirs(r'D:\Publico\PA03_15_NOVEMBRO\\'+x)

for x in users15:
    os.makedirs(r'D:\Publico\PA04_JUNDIAÍ\\'+x)
```

Answer (score 3):

A função `os.rmdir` chama diretamente a APi do sistema operacional equivalente a essa chamada, e, tradicionalmente, essa chamada só apaga mesmo um diretório vazio.

No entanto, a linguagem Python inclui, além dessas chamadas diretas, o módulo `shutil` que tem algumas facilidades para manipulação de arquivos. Entre elas está o `shutil.rmtree` - essa sim, uma chamada que recebendo um diretório como argumento, apaga todos os conteúdos além do diretório em si:

```py
import shutil
...
shutil.rmtree(r'D:\Publico')
```

Comment: ótimo era exatamente o que eu precisava as 2 respostas vão servir diretamente na API que estou desenvolvendo , obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Para você conseguir excluir o diretório, você deverá primeiro apagar os arquivos e pastas dentro dele. Utilize a função `walk` para percorrer todos os arquivos e subpastas do diretório raiz e apague-os utilizando o `remove`.

Exemplo:

```
import os

def rmdir(path):
    for dir_,dirnames,filenames in list(os.walk(path))[::-1]:
        for filename in filenames:
            filename = os.path.normpath(dir_+'\\'+filename)
            print("Removendo",filename,"...")
            os.remove(filename)
        print("Removendo",os.path.normpath(dir_),"...")
        os.rmdir(dir_)

rmdir("<Coloque aqui seu diretório>")
```

No exemplo acima eu estou percorrendo todos os diretórios e arquivos e removendo-os um por um. A função `walk` retorna um gerador, e para que tudo funcione, eu preciso apagar os arquivos e pastas mais internos primeiro. Para isso, eu transformo ele numa lista e inverto a sua ordem.

Além disso você também pode utilizar a função `rmtree` do módulo `shutil`. Essa função irá remover o diretório sem precisar antes excluir os arquivos dentro.

Comment: Pode usar a [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) para remover um diretório não vazio.

Comment: ótimo era exatamente o que eu precisava as 2 respostas vão servir diretamente na API que estou desenvolvendo , obrigado!